# Show ad div depending on which tab is visible

Tags: jquery

I have two div's that holds banner ads loaded dynamically from an ad server,the main one is "#bannerTop" and the other is "#brokerageBanner". Only one div that holds these ads needs to be visible at a time based on what tab is active. The page has a tab set up for each type of partner, which there are really only two - brokerage partners and all others. I need to show "#brokerageBanner" only when the tab "#BrokContent" is visible. Should I use the appended url "/partners#Brokerage" or the div that holds that content "#BrokContent" to trigger which banner ad is shown? I am having some isues with this:

```
if ($("#BrokContent").is(:visible)) {
   $("#brokerageBanner").show();
   $("#bannerTop").hide();
 } else {
 $("#bannerTop").show();
 $("#brokerageBanner").hide();
}
```

thanks

Comment: "some issues"? The JS is the preferable of the two, can you clarify what problem you have? (assuming the missing quote mark on line 2, and hash on line 6 isn't it)

Comment: Also: 81 questions, 54% accept - might want to do something about that.

Comment: @annakata - thx, really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) is a selector and needs to be un quotes, like this:

```
if ($("#BrokContent").is(":visible")) {
  $("#brokerageBanner").show();
  $("#bannerTop").hide();
} else {
  $("#bannerTop").show();
  $("#brokerageBanner").hide();
}
```

Or a bit more concise using [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like this:

```
var bcVisible = $("#BrokContent").is(":visible");
$("#brokerageBanner").toggle(bcVisible);
$("#bannerTop").toggle(!bcVisible);
```

Comment: so it was just the quotes huh? I like the second, shorter is better. thanks Nick!

Comment: I ended up having to use both, once so the when the page loads the appropriate banner is loaded, then a click function for when you click and change tabs to get it to switch....this is messy though, can you help?if ($("#BrokContent").is(":visible")) {
     $("#brokerAd").show();
     $("#bannerContain").hide();
   } else {
     $("#bannerContain").show();
     $("#brokerAd").hide();
   }
   
   $("ul#flowtabs li a").click(function(){
    var bcVisible = $("#BrokContent").is(":visible");
    $("#brokerAd").toggle(bcVisible);
    $("#bannerContain").toggle(!bcVisible);
   });